# Why would my list of Wordpress categories be showing drafts and trash count?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using this piece of code to show a list of categories that are in a certain taxonomy, and the amount of post within that category.

Whenever I delete the post, the post count still includes the deleted post and shows that category title, this also applies to a post that has been placed into a draft as well. It isn't until I permanently delete the post that the category and/or count disappears.

What am I missing?

```
<?php $args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'orderby'            => 'slug',
'order'              => 'ASC',
'style'              => 'list',
'show_count'         => 1,
'hide_empty'         => 1,
'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
'child_of'           => 0,
'feed'               => '',
'feed_type'          => '',
'feed_image'         => '',
'exclude'            => '',
'exclude_tree'       => '',
'include'            => '',
'hierarchical'       => 1,
'title_li'           => __( '' ),
'show_option_none'   => __('No categories'),
'number'             => null,
'echo'               => 0,
'depth'              => 0,
'current_category'   => 0,
'pad_counts'         => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'artists',
'walker'             => null
); 
$variable = wp_list_categories($args);
$variable = preg_replace('/\<\/a\> \((.*)\)/',' <span class="quantity">$1</span></a>',$variable);


echo $variable;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a little google search and on the Wordpress forms I came across this piece of code to place into my functions.php file, although it doesn't seem to allow me to quick edit, but it does fix the post count problem...

```
// Function that helps the post count
add_action('edited_term_taxonomy','yoursite_edited_term_taxonomy',10,2);
function yoursite_edited_term_taxonomy($term,$taxonomy) {
  global $wpdb,$post;
  //in quick edit mode, $post is an array()
  //in full edit mode $post is an object
  if ( is_array( $post ))
    $posttype=$post['post_type'];
  else
    $posttype=$post->post_type;
  if ($posttype) {
    $DB_prefix=$wpdb->get_blog_prefix(BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE);
    $sql = "UPDATE ".$DB_prefix."term_taxonomy tt
          SET count =
          (SELECT count(p.ID) FROM  ".$DB_prefix."term_relationships tr
          LEFT JOIN ".$DB_prefix."posts p
          ON (p.ID = tr.object_id AND p.post_type = '".$posttype."' AND p.post_status =     'publish')
          WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
          WHERE tt.taxonomy = '".$taxonomy->name."'
      ";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
  }
}
```

Wish I could explain it, but I'm very new to PHP...